# Eclipse is giving me warnings incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

Eclipse is telling me that

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
```

is never used however it is used and if I remove parse it becomes removed 
it is causing my app to not work. 
What should I do

Comment: prss `ctrl+shift+o` and then save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> organizes your import statements, so try with that and save the file. If that doesn't work, try a Build and Clean of your project.